# What is the path of any internal memory folder that I can see without being root? AndroidStudio

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

Well, the problem I have is that the address I use so far in f.exist () is /data/data/com.example.mmripre/files/
The problem is that I can't see it from my phone to analyze the data, so I need the path of another folder which if I can see

Answer (score 0):

you can view the device file directly from android studio. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer

simply click "device file explorer" on the right hand side of the IDE

> 1. Click View > Tool Windows > Device File Explorer or click the Device
>      File Explorer button in the tool window bar to open the Device File
>      Explorer.
> 2. Select a device from the drop down list.
> 3. Interact with the device content in the file explorer window.
>      Right-click on a file or
>      directory to create a new file or directory, save the selected file or
>      directory to your machine, upload, delete, or synchronize.
>      Double-click a file to open it in Android Studio.
>
> Android Studio saves files you open this way in a temporary directory
>   outside of your project. If you make modifications to a file you
>   opened using the Device File Explorer, and would like to save your
>   changes back to the device, you must manually upload the modified
>   version of the file to the device.

[image]

Comment: note that you can only analyse your file from the data/data/your_project folder directly if you install it in debug mode. It'll say you don't have permission if you install the app in release